# smallcheck what does "but n did not meet ==>" and how do I know which

Tags: haskell, testing, smallcheck

I wrote this property

```
prop_lookupsymbol = forAll $ \name table scope -> case lookupsymbol name table scope of
                                                  Just (s,_) -> property $ is_ancestor s scope
                                                  Nothing ->  forAll $ \s->is_ancestor s ==> (lookupsymbol name table s) == Nothing
```

and ran it with `smallCheck 3 prop_lookupsymbol`, the results are :

> Completed 9000 tests without failure.
>   But 9000 did not meet ==> condition.

I know it refers to `==>` call in the property but what does it mean by `did not meet` ? Should I worry about this ? and if yes then how do I get the tests that didn't meet the condition ?

### Edit

I had a mistake where `is_ancestor` was lacking a second parameter, so the property is this now :

```
   prop_lookupsymbol = forAll $ \name table scope -> case lookupsymbol name table scope of
                                                  Just (s,_) -> property $ is_ancestor s scope
                                                  Nothing ->  forAll $ \s->is_ancestor s scope ==> (lookupsymbol name table s) == Nothing
```

But from 9000 there are 8340 which didn't meet the condition.

## Here is explanation of the types and functions above :

`SymbolTable` is a type synonym for `HashMap (Scope,String) Symbol` (`HashMap.Strict` from unordered-containers package), this is simply for building a compiler :).

Symbol has variety of constructors(variable,function,type,etc) and `Scope`defines in what scope the symbol is defined, we have file,class,function,method(function in class),interface.

Scope has name(file name, class name , etc) and upper scope, for a class it also has the parent scope(parent as in inheritance) and a list of interfaces scopes(which the class implements), the interface scope has a parent scope along with its upper scope.

The function `is_ancestor s1 s2` returns whether s1 is an upperscope of s2 (or upper-upperscope or upper-upper-upper...) or is a parent scope(or parent-parent or parent-parent-...) or one of the interfaces(or the parent's interfaces or etc), I should mention that `is_ancestor s s` is always true.

Finally `lookupsymbol name table scope` tries to find a symbol whose name is `name` and scope is `s` where `is_ancestor s scope` is true, its return type is `Maybe (Scope,Symbol)` meaning that it returns the found symbol along with the scope the symbol is defined in(and Nothing when nothing is found).

My property states this : for any name table scope, if lookupsymbol returns `Just (s,_)` then `s` must be `is_ancestor` of `scope`, but if it returns nothing then it will return nothing for any scope that `is_ancestor` of `scope`.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it is referring to the fact that false implies anything, so if `is_parent s` is false it won't even look at the rest. This is useful information if you are using an `==>` to 'filter' values from a bigger set. Technically your tests passed, but in every case (ie 9000/9000) it did not evaluate the RHS of `==>`. Seems to imply it never tests a node with parents? But I'm not certain how this number interacts with the `forAll`.

Comment: Very generally, yes, you should worry when a large majority of your tests do not meet the `==>` condition. Either your test is structured wrong or you're not generating all the test cases you mean to.

Comment: @dfeuer that was actually the real code, thanks you showed me a typo , I'll edit my question :)

Comment: 8340 out of 9000 isn't *nearly* as bad as 9000 out of 9000. In fact, you might consider that acceptable!

Comment: FYI, the relationship you call "parent" is conventionally called "ancestor". You should probably change your terminology to avoid confusion.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree with you :)